# Jquery ContextMenu

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

I have a page where there are divs which are of 2 types (router & switch) differentiated by attribute 'type'. I want to have different menus when I right click them. So what I did is get all divs with type router using jquery selector and iterate over them to bind the context menu. The issue which I face is when I right click on a menu item which in turn will invoke a jquery modal dialog for that div id, now if I invoke the same menu on another div the dialog is invoked for the first div id also. The code :

```
function createMenu() {
    var divList = $("div[type^='Router']");
    for ( var i = 0; i < divList.length; i++) {
        // alert(divList[i].id);
        $("#" + divList[i].id).contextMenu({
            menu : 'routerMenu'
        }, function(action, el, pos) {
            var name = $(el).attr('name');
            if(action == 'dialog') {
                            alert(name);
                invokeDialog(name,'Router');
            }
        });
    }
    var divList = $("div[type^='Switch']");
    for ( var i = 0; i < divList.length; i++) {
        // alert(divList[i].id);
        $("#" + divList[i].id).contextMenu({
            menu : 'switchMenu'
        }, function(action, el, pos) {
            var name = $(el).attr('name');
            if(action == 'dialog') {
                            alert(name);
                invokeDialog(name,'Switch');
            }
        });
        }
}
```

For example, there are two divs of the same type 'Router' with ids id1 and id2. First I click on id1, I get an alert with id1's name. Next I click on id2, I get an alert id1 and then id2. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?